# Rails project: Deletion confirmation not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails 3.2 project, in `app/views/sites/index.html.erb`, I show all the sites, with a link to deletion.

```
<% @sites.each do |site| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= site.url %></td>
    <td><%= site.html %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', site, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Hey, are you sure?' } %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

In `app/controllers/sites_controller.rb`, I have the `destroy` method:

```
def destroy
  @site = Site.find(params[:id])
  @site.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to sites_url }
  end
end
```

The deletion works, but it doesn't show the confirmation box 'Hey, are you sure?'... and I can't see why.

Comment: Your code looks correct. The same works for me.

Comment: Interesting... not sure why it doesn't work for me then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the hash data: link_to ("Destroy", site, :method=> :delete, :confirm=> "Hey, are you sure?"). See the doc http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: It gave:
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...r.append= ( link_to ("Destroy", site, :method=> :delete, :co...

Comment: Ah this works: link_to 'Destroy', site, method: :delete, confirm: 'Hey, are you sure?'. Thanks!

Comment: Probably was a space after the link_to, so the error. But the syntax used by you is cleaner.